# Pyspark: the most frequent words

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, count

I have a dataframe  with columns :languages and words

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('eng', "cat"),
    ('eng', 'cat'),
    ('eng','dog'),
    ('eng','cat')
], ["lang", "text"])
sdf.show()

+----+----+
|lang|text|
+----+----+
| eng| cat|
| eng| cat|
| eng| dog|
| eng| cat|
+----+----+
```

I want to group the top words by language(what i expect):

```
lang        count_words 
eng      {'cat':3,'dog':1}
```

I do this:

```
grouped = sdf.groupBy("lang").agg(count('text').alias("count_words"))
```

But i understand that I need to use **create_map()** here, but I don't quite understand how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by both "text" and "lang" and then use the create_map() as you intended to.
Here it is:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, count
    grouped = sdf.groupBy(["lang", "text"]).agg(create_map('text', count('text')).alias('count_words'))
```